# How to display random users with avatars

Tags: functions, shortcode, users, buddypress, avatar

I adapted a little [a function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/69601/25187) to display a number of random users with their avatars with a shortcode. It works, but something is not good. Sometimes it displays with one user less than I want (just a blank line instead of the first user), sometimes it includes the administrator, although it should not. What is wrong with my code?

```
add_shortcode( 'random_users', 'display_random_users' );
//Usage: [random_users how_many = 3]

function display_random_users( $atts ) {

    extract(shortcode_atts( array( "how_many" => '' ), $atts ) );

    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'role' => 'subscriber',
        'fields' => 'ID'
    );

    $users = get_users( $args );
    $users = array_rand( $users, $how_many );

    foreach ( $users as $userID ) {
        echo '<a href="' . 
            bp_core_get_user_domain( $userID ) . '">' . 
            bp_core_fetch_avatar( array( 'item_id' => $userID ) ) . '<br />' . 
            xprofile_get_field_data( '1', $userID ) . '</a><br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Do a print_r($users) to see what your query is returning. That way you can make sure you're only getting subscribers, not admins. Also, does get_users not support orderby=rand? I know wp_query does, but not sure about get_users. If it does, it would be easier to only query the amount of users in $how_many instead.

Comment: @gdaniel This is what returned the `print_r($users)`: **Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 23 )**. So, the first user is inexistent and the second is the admin, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure why your query is returning more IDs than necessary. The `$args` for get_users look correct.

By default get_users does not support `orderby=rand`, but you can overwrite that option. See below:

```
function random_user_query( &$query )
{
    $query->query_orderby = "ORDER BY RAND()";
}

// Usage: [random_users how_many = 3]
add_shortcode( 'random_users', 'display_random_users' );
function display_random_users( $atts ) {

    shortcode_atts( array( "how_many" => '', ), $atts );

    // Create a function to override the ORDER BY clause
    add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'random_user_query' );

    $users = get_users( array(
        'role'    => 'subscriber',
        'fields'  => 'ID',
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'number'  => $atts['how_many'],
    ) );

    foreach ( $users as $userID ) {
        printf( 
            '<a href="%s">%s<br />%s</a><br />',
            bp_core_get_user_domain( $userID ),
            bp_core_fetch_avatar( array( 'item_id' => $userID ) ),
            xprofile_get_field_data( '1', $userID )
        );
    }

    // Remove the hook
    remove_action( 'pre_user_query', 'random_user_query' );
}
```

This way, you only query $how_many users, instead of querying all users and then filtering out $how_many.

I found this hook [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20606).

Comment: The `orderby` in $args must appear twice? However, it seems that the function works well. Thank you!

Comment: I think the `'orderby' => 'ID'` is not nedeed, so I removed it.

Comment: It was not needed, I missed that. I removed it.

Comment: As PHP 5.2 and anonymous functions are gone now with 5.3 dead ([see those stats about secure versions](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/12/php-install-statistics.html)), I'd suggest to use a Closure: `add_action( 'pre_user_query', function( $q ) { ... } );` instead. Anyway, +1 for the answer :)

Comment: @kaiser, thanks for letting me know. I was not aware of that.

Comment: I hope you don't mind the edit. Else removing the action wouldn't have been possible. More info about that problem in [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57079/how-to-remove-a-filter-that-is-an-anonymous-object/57088#57088) and in [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137688/remove-actions-filters-added-via-anonymous-functions).